# Teamviewer Remote Computer showing black instead of Login Screen

Tags: windows, teamviewer

I'm trying to connect to my remote server using teamviewer 12.0.81460. It used to work absolutely fine. But from past few days I see a black screen when I connect using TeamViewer(see attached screenshot). But when I move the cursor it starts showing some points on the screen but that's also not clear. One thing I noticed is that **when I connect with remote desktop from another PC and bypass this login screen** it works **fine**. But this login screen has some issue. 
The solution I have tried so far:

1. Changing screen resolution
2. Disabling black screen on my TeamViewer Settings
3. Installing a lower version (11) on my PC but
   it asks me to upgrade since

   remote PC is running latest version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Remote Login screen]

Comment: this is bug in previous version... here is link of threat on its official site. https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-12/Only-Black-Screen-on-Host-with-TeamViewer-12/m-p/1802#M291.. Have a look and  upgrade your team viewer on remote machine.

Comment: the latest version of TeamViewer is running on both Machines i.e. 12.0.81460

Comment: but according to team viewer's support team , this is a bug in their application and fixed. so i suggest you to submit your query direct .

Comment: Response from TeamViewer Team:
Please try the following on the remote computer:

 

- stop TeamViewer service (task manager, service tab)

- open regedit, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer (32bit system)  OR HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\TeamViewer (64bit system)

- create a DWORD named "EnableHooks". Leave the value at zero.

- start TeamViewer service again

Answer (score -1):

I know this is late, but i had the a similar issue where i was trying to connect from my windows computer to mac computer and got stuck at a black login screen. The workaround i have found to be useful is as follows:

1. Type the first letter of the account i wanted to login to
2. Press ENTER
3. type account
4. Press Enter

The screen was still black and shows anything until i reach step 4, it redirects me to the account! This was because although the screen was not working, the keyboard was working on remote computer.